# How i can create VIEW table using Drupal hook_schema()

Tags: 7, views, database

i want to create a view table in my custom module *.install* file and i want join with another table like i did in my `db_query` function but i want this thing in `hook_schema` function.

```
 db_query('CREATE VIEW Sample_Label_Data_By_CategoryId AS
                select
                `sample_label_library`.`SampleNumber` AS `SampleNumber`,
                `sample_label_category`.`CategoryName` AS `CategoryName`,
                `sample_label_and_category`.`CategoryID` AS `CategoryID`,
                `sample_label_library`.`MaterialName` AS `MaterialName`,
                `sample_label_library`.`EPANumber` AS `EPANumber`,
                `sample_label_library`.`SampleFilename` AS `SampleFilename`,
                `sample_label_library`.`LabelFilename` AS `LabelFilename`
                from ((`sample_label_and_category` join `sample_label_library`
                    on((`sample_label_and_category`.`SampleNumber` = `sample_label_library`.`SampleNumber`)))
                    join `sample_label_category` on((`sample_label_and_category`.`CategoryID` = `sample_label_category`.`CategoryID`)))')
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hook_schema()` is only used to return a structured array representing your module's database tables. You can't execute a query from it. Well, you physically can, but you shouldn't.

Since `hook_schema()` is used on install, your code to create the View should be in [`hook_install()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install/7.x), and the code to remove it should be in [`hook_uninstall()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_uninstall/7.x)